# 2D sprite not looking at camera from above

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D sprite and its always facing the camera in Y and Z axis, but the problem appears only when the camera is at an angle from the top. At this point I want the sprite to be flat on X axis but that does not work. I have tried using transform.lookAt() and also eulerAngles but does not work.

```
this.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(Camera.main.eulerAngles.x, Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y+180f, Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.z);
//transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform, -Vector3.up);
```

Comment: Did you not just answer your own issue with "its always facing camera in Y" given Y is up and down, and you want a from the top and you want it pointing to x, surely your angle sould be for X and Z not Y?

Comment: So if the camera is looking at an angle down from the top ( rotated x = 90), the sprite should also be at rotated angle x = 90.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the 3rd dimension in a 2D app?

Comment: Its an AR app which is the reason this is being a problem

Comment: Why did you use `-Vector3.up`? Shouldn't it be just `Vector2.up`? Please explain what you mean by "does not work"

Comment: I shall try with Vector2.up.